# What are the operations for each Alloy utility module?

Tags: alloy

The utility modules provided by Alloy are listed on this web page:

http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/quickguide/util.html

But that doesn't list the operations provided by each module. For example, the web page says there is an ordering module, but it doesn't say what operations are provided by the ordering module.

Where are the operations for each module documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open them in the analyzer (under File | Open Sample Models) and you can see all the ops listed with comments explaining each.